# How do I pass on script arguments that contain quotes/spaces?

Tags: bash, quoting

I'm trying to write a script `notify-finish` that can be prepended to any command. When done, it will run the command given by the arguments following, then email the user when the command is complete. Here's what I have:

```
PROG=$1
# Run command given by arguments
$@
ECODE=$?
echo -e "Subject: `hostname`: $PROG finished\r\nTo: <$USER>\r\n\r\nExited with $ECODE\r\n" | sendmail $USER
```

This works most of the time, but when arguments contain spaces, the quoting is stripped off.

Working example:

```
notify-finished rsync -avz source/ user@remote:dest/
```

Failing example:

```
notify-finished rsync -avz -e 'ssh -c blowfish' source/ user@remote:dest/
```

In the second case, `$@` is expanded out to `rsync -avz -e ssh -c blowfish source user@remote:dest/`, missing the single quotes. It does not work with double-quotes either, nor with `$*`.

After reading other posts I tried putting the command in an array, but I get the exact same issue:

```
CMD=(notify-finished rsync -avz -e 'ssh -c blowfish' source/ user@remote:dest/)
${CMD[@]}
```

How do I make this work for all arguments?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `"$@"` *with* quotes:

```
prog="$1"
"$@"
ecode="$?"
echo "$prog exited with $ecode"
```

This will pass each argument exactly as it was received. If you don't include the quotes, each element will be split according to `$IFS`:

- `"$@"` is like `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`, passing each element as a separate argument.
- `"$*"` is like `"$1 $2 $3 ..."`, passing all elements concatenated as a single argument
- `$*` and `$@` is like `$1 $2 $3 ...`, breaking up each element on whitespace, expanding all globs, and passing each resulting word as a separate element (`$IFS`).

The same is true for arrays, such as `"${array[@]}"` and `"${array[*]}"`

Comment: This is special behaviour specifically for `$@` within double quotes.

Comment: This worked perfectly. A while ago, I had it assigning `$@` to `ARGS`. As in `ARGS=$@` and then doing `$PROG $ARGS` so this wouldn't have worked. Thank you

Comment: @axon: If you want to store the arguments in a variable, you can do it with an array variable: `ARGS=("$@"); "$PROG" "${ARGS[@]}"`

Answer (score 4):

Put double-quotes around your variable substitutions to keep them from being parsed (note that this applies to all variables: `$@`, `$1`, and `$PROG`).  Also: don't put a $ before a variable name when assigning to it; use `#` for comments; and, on the last line, the single-quotes will prevent variables from being substituted at all.

```
PROG="$1"
shift
# Run program below
"$PROG" "$@"
ECODE=$? # note: this will always be a number, so it doesn't have to be protected with double-quotes
echo -e "Subject: $(hostname): $PROG finished\r\nTo: <$USER>\r\n\r\nExited with $ECODE\r\n' | sendmail "$USER"
```

Comment: If you're going to break off the first parameter, don't forget to `shift` before you use `"$@"`