# How to make a command-line argument variable contain the backslashes that mark spaces and other special characters?

Tags: linux, bash

Consider the script `print_folder.sh`:

```
echo $1
ls -F $1
```

This simple script expects a user to supply the name of a folder through the first argument. The script will first print out the name of the folder and then it's contents.

Now, let's consider two cases of `$1`: the one when `$1` doesn't and the one when `$1` does contain spaces.

---

**Case 1: No Spaces**

```
[nikola@leviathan ~]$ ./print_folder.sh Pictures/
Pictures/
Gifs/  Miscellaneous/  Screenshots/  Wallpapers/
```

No problems, everything works fine.

**Case 2: Spaces**

```
[nikola@leviathan ~]$ ./print_folder.sh Templates/URxvt\ Colorschemes/
Templates/URxvt Colorschemes/
ls: cannot access 'Templates/URxvt': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Colorschemes/': No such file or directory
```

See, here is the problem. The cause of it is obviously that `$1` has the value of `Templates/URxvt Colorschemes` instead of `Templates/URxvt\ Colorschemes`.

---

How can I make `$1` contains the backslashes that signify special characters instead of removing them? Also, keep in mind that I will not accept workarounds like *making `ls` read spaces "normally" (i.e.  is read as a space in a folder's name instead of another folder's name)* since I don't use `$1` as an argument only to `ls` so that may be not possible with other commands.

Comment: Use double-quotes around the argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/56041), [Bash variables with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5819423/608639), [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/608639), [How do I pass on script arguments that contain quotes/spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5720194/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

The better, safer and simpler way of having `ls` (or any command) parse your variable as a single argument rather than two would be to instead of inserting backlashes into the variable surround your surround it with quotes when using it: `ls -F "$1"`.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered many times before. In this instance I think it is better to find a mature duplicate rather than restating something that has been stated many times before.

Comment: Right, should have thought of that. Will keep it in mind in the future :)