# Unable to pass " ' " as a command-line argument

Tags: c, bash, for-loop, command-line-arguments

I can't pass strings that contain an apostrophe as a command-line argument.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
unsigned int ascii_values (const char *word);
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./ascii WORD\n");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int ascii = ascii_values(argv[i]);
        printf("The ascii value is %i\n", ascii);
    }
}

unsigned int ascii_values (const char *word)
{
    int l = strlen(word);
    int ascii = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        ascii = word[i];
    }
    return ascii;
}
```

If I input the command-line arguments into the terminal:

```
./ascii '
```

The following happens and gets stuck there:

```
>
```

Instead of:

```
The ascii value is 39.
```

Any idea of why it's doing that?

Comment: `./ascii \'` or `./ascii "'"`

Comment: This is an issue with how you are using the shell, not your C code. `'` has special meaning to the shell, so you need to escape it to pass a *literal* single quote as an argument.

Comment: The `>` is the secondary prompt; the shell is waiting for more input to complete the quoted word you just started to input.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, This isn't a dupe of [that Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720194/how-do-i-pass-on-script-arguments-that-contain-quotes-spaces). Not only is the question different, but none of the answers apply here. I looked for while, and couldn't find anything about quoting single-quotes.  (The closest was quoting single-quotes inside of a single-quoted literal.)

Comment: @Alex Sugimoto  Try invoking a command like `cat '` or `grep '` or even `date '`.  Then when you get that `>` prompt, try typing another `'`.  (And if you do that with your program, you'll end up with the ASCII value for a newline character!)

Answer (score 2):

Single quote is a special shell character so you have to escape it.  Either enter it as `\'`or `"'"`.